# NuGet problems: can't get (newly generated) empty AspNetCore app to work anymore

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I can't get my VS2019 installation to create empty aspnetcore projects anymore. It worked fine a few days ago, I don't know what broke it. I've been searching for hours, can't find a solution.

Here's the current situation: when I let VS2019 create an empty aspnetcore project, this is how my solution explorer looks:

[image: Solution explorer screenshot]

As you can see, nuget packages are not getting downloaded or loaded.

When I right-click the solution and select 'restore nuget packages', this is what I found in 'Package Manager' output:

> All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
>   Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.2193440
>   ========== Finished ==========
>
> Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: An error occurred while
>   retrieving package metadata for
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations.2.2.0' from source
>   'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder'.

Running nuget locals -clear all didn't help.
I tried repairing .net core 2.2 sdk installation, didn't help.

I'm not sure how to continue or what to try next.

Any ideas?

---

EDIT 2019-04-28:

It's also broken in VS2017. When I create a brand new empty aspnetcore 2.1 project (screenshot above is 2.2), I get similar errors:

[image: 2016 Solution explorer screenshot]

Trying to restore NuGet packages gives:

> Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: An error occurred while
>   retrieving package metadata for
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.5.2.0' from source
>   'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder'.

Something is seriously broken, but I can't seem to figure it out... :(

Comment: delete obj folder so that VS/Nuget rebuilds the  `project.assets.json`

Comment: Tried this to no avail. After removing the obj folder, I have to restore nuget packages to generate project.assets.json. This gives me the same error as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the source of my problem:

Some .nuspec files in C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder were invalid. They did not contain valid xml, but a few kilobytes of binary 0x00 data.

No idea why this happened.

Renaming the filter to 'xxxNuGetFallbackFolder' seemed to temporary fix my problem, I can now create new aspnetcore projects again.

---

For people with a similar problem: this is how I got to the root:

- Download nuget from https://www.nuget.org/downloads
- Place it inside the solution folder
- Run nuget restore -verbosity detailed

Comment: you should have been able to get the same information from `dotnet restore --verbosity detailed` given your project is SDK style. Not that this information helps you now.

Comment: Zivkan's dotnet restore fixed this for me